# Do non-verbal predicates discharge thematic roles?

Tags: syntax, theta-role

I'm fairly familiar with verbal predicates (*VP-shell, passivisation, PISH* etc.) but every time I have a **non-verbal predicate, like NP or AP**, I seem to struggle - partially because I don't know whether they discharge any thematic (theta) roles.

> John considered him a good person

This example is especially tricky and the question of NP discharging theta roles may be really helpful.

It seems to me that *him* receives two theta roles - one from "a good person" and second from "consider".

[image]

That clearly violates the Theta-criterion.

What do you think?
Thanks for shedding any light on this problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you've labelled the uppermost node 'VP' rather than 'clause'. "Jake" is an NP functioning as subject. "Considers him a good person" is the predicate/VP where "considers" is predicator, "him" is direct object and "a good person" is an NP functioning as objective predicative complement.

Comment: @BillJ I omitted the sentential constituents TP and CP. What I do as well is follow the PISH hypothesis, so I initially put the subject inside the VP.